# Calculation of the Inertia of cylidrical weights fixed to a flywheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

I am required to calculate the inertia of a flywheel and was wondering if anyone could help me with calculating the inertia of cylindrical weights attached to the flywheel. I’ve attached a diagram to illustrate the system in question. (let disk weigh 500g and each weight weigh 100g) I understand that to calculate the inertia of the disk its simply $I= 0.5*0.5*(0.120^2+0.020^2)$ but how can I calculate the inertia of the additional weights.

Thank you for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up "Parallel Axis Theorem," which will tell you how to do this when a shape is moved off the axis of rotation.

Also, the general formula for $I$ of a point mass is:

$$I=mr^2$$

In this situation the purple cylinder weights are approximately point loads like this, and you can estimate the answer in this way. Since you are given the radii of the cylinders, your instructor may want you to be more precise than this. In that case use Parallel Axis Theorem.